# Create RewriteRule Split query string in .htaccess for _escaped_fragment_

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am redirecting requests to snapshots directory for google hashbang.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /snapshots/%1? [NC,L]
```

So: http://site/?_escaped_fragment_=/detail/10

Go here: site/snapshots/detail/10

But I want to ignore the second params so 
http://site/?_escaped_fragment_=/detail/10/12-12-2014

Should be redirect to the same url
site/snapshots/detail/10

Any idea how I should rewrite the rules?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)$
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?([^/]+(?:/[^/]+|))
```

So the regex will only attempt to capture as many as 2 virtual paths.